# Permission error when running jar from python

Tags: python, jar

I have a .jar archive that loads a file and then does some things with it and writes it to the disk again.

If I call this .jar directly from the command prompt, everything works. But when I try to do it from within python, I get the following error:

```
Input file ("C:\xxx.txt") was not found or was not readable.
```

This is my python code:

```
import sys, os, subprocess

if os.path.isdir(sys.argv[1]):
    for file in os.listdir("."):
        print (" ".join(['java', '-jar', sys.argv[2], 'd', "\"" + os.path.abspath(file) + "\"", "\""+os.path.join(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(file)), "output"), file) + "\""]))

        subprocess.call(['java', '-jar', sys.argv[2], 'd', "\"" + os.path.abspath(file) + "\"", "\""+os.path.join(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(file)), "output"), file) + "\""])
```

When I copy the printed statement into the commandline, the jar executes perfectly; everything works. I tried running cmd as an admin, but that didn't help.

Comment: As a side note, you can just write `'"'` instead of `"\""`. It's a lot more readable.

Comment: Also, you don't need `os.path.join(os.path.join(foo, bar), baz)`, just `os.path.join(foo, bar, baz)` will do the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. It's the first time that I'm using os.path.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the extra quotes you're adding. When you pass `subprocess` a list of args, it already quotes them appropriately; if you quote them yourself, it'll end up quoting your quotes, so instead of passing an argument that, when unquoted, means `C:\xxx.txt`, you'll be passing an argument that, when unquoted, means `"C:\xxx.txt"`, which is not a valid pathname.

The rule of thumb for Windows* is: If you know exactly what each argument should be, pass them as a list, and don't try to quote them yourself; if you know exactly what the final command-line string should be, pass it as a string, and don't try to break it into a list of separate arguments yourself.

---

* Note that this is only for Windows. On POSIX, unless you're using `shell=True`, you should basically *never* use a string.

Comment: Thanks. I had it without the quotes at first, but then of course my printed statement wouldn't run in cmd so I thought that that was my mistake.

Comment: @Dauntless: If you want to create strings that you can run in cmd, you can; just pass the exact same string you printed out to `call`, instead of breaking it down into a list.